# How do I disable input field when certain select list value is picked

Tags: javascript, disabled-input

How do I disable and make the input field text to hidden when certain value is selected from select list?  In my code, I need to disable and make the input text to hidden when "United States" is selected from my drop down.

My HTML: 
[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/antwonlee/cf4Sz/8/)

My Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('BillingCountryCode').onchange = function () {
    if(this.value != '840') {
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince").style.display="none"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince").style.display="block"
    }
}
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. If you're trying to hide that second input, "Other States", you must give it a different ID than the other, or use classes instead. This won't completely solve your problem either, since you problem want to hide the label "Other States". It would be best to wrap both inputs in an element and hide/show the wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your fiddle is you have two elements with the same ID.  You can do exactly what is already there, just change the ID on either the state dropdown or the text input.  Updated code might look like this, if you simply name the text input the same with a 2:

```
document.getElementById('BillingCountryCode').onchange = function () {
    if(this.value != '840') {
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince2").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince2").style.display="block";
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince2").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way around it.  The 3rd party that I am using to process the form uses the ID to process the card.  Is there way you can add a Class instead of ID for the "BillingStateProvince2" ?

Comment: Absolutely, you can find the element however you would like, name, id, class, etc.  I think the real answer is that your HTML is not valid, and personally I would use a different method to make this work such as assigning the ID in your conditional blocks.  While you can use plain Javascript to loop through and find the proper class, it might be easier in this specific case for you to use jQuery.

Comment: How would you achieve this goal  using jQuery? I try doing this:document.getElementById('BillingCountryCode').onchange = function () {
    if(this.value != '840') {
        $('#BillingStateProvince').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("BillingStateProvince").style.display="block";
        $('.OtherStateProvince').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}

Comment: It's hard to say exactly without knowing more, but here is a fiddle of how I might go about this: http://jsfiddle.net/duffmaster33/6xhTP/   Should at least get you on the right path.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.  If this solved your question, can you mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If i got the question , simply invert the `if` condition like this :

```
if(this.value === "840") { ... }
```

here is the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/antwonlee/cf4Sz/7/