# Javascript disable/enable input field based on selection other field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to follow answer here to do this in my code: [How do I disable input field when certain select list value is picked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547929/how-do-i-disable-input-field-when-certain-select-list-value-is-picked) but not working for me.

I have an HTML select field id 'TfL' with Yes/No answer, and next field 'TfLroad' is an input field. I want 'TfLroad' to load as disabled by default, then if 'TfL' changes from No to Yes, then 'TfLroad' should be enabled.

Whole page code below, JS at top of file, these two fields next to bottom, tx any suggestions!:

```
{% extends "base.jinja2" %}
{% block content %}

<script>

// value 0 for No answer to TfL road 1 for, in which case disabled, on change should
// enable TfLroad element by setting disabled = false, but not working yet!

document.getElementById("TfLroad").onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("TfLroad").disabled = true;
}

document.getElementById('TfL').onchange = function () {
    if(this.value = '0') {
        document.getElementById("TfLroad").disabled = true;
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("TfLroad").disabled = false;
    }
}


</script>
                <h2 style="text-align:center">Add A 'Dummy' Street</h2>

<p>You can create a Dummy street here, which you will be able to search for in this application. This is to
demonstrate how a real Create &amp; Update Process could work for this application, without corrupting the original
data. Dummy streets are indicated in search results.</p>

<form class="form-horizontal" action = "" method="post">
  <fieldset>

     <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label for="stname" class="control-label">Street Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="stname" name="stname" pattern="^\S.{3,98}\S$"
                   title="Sorry, you must type from 5 to 100 characters, and no space at beginning or end."
                   placeholder="Full Street Name" required>
            <!--  required attribute needed because empty string bypasses the pattern regex. -->
            <span class="help-block">NB: No naughty word streets please, these will be deleted by admin!</span>
        </div>

<!-- CR, CL, PR, 25, 16, 19, BE, KN, SC, TH, WA, WH -->
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="distr" class="control-label">Postal District</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="distr" name="distr">
              <option>Croydon (CR0, CR2, CR7 or CR9)</option>
              <option>Coulsdon CR5</option>
              <option>Purley CR8</option>
              <option>London SE25</option>
              <option>London SW16</option>
              <option>Kenley CR8</option>
              <option>South Croydon CR2</option>
              <option>Thornton Heath CR7</option>
              <option>Warlingham CR6</option>
              <option>Whyteleafe CR3</option>
              <option>Beckenham BR3</option>
            </select>
            <span class="help-block">NB: Original data uses postal district only, hence problem with several postcodes for Croydon.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="maint" class="control-label">Who looks after this street?</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="maint" name="maint">
              <option>Croydon Borough</option>
              <option>Transport for London</option>
              <option>Private Road</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h4 class="centre">Street Number Limits for this Street Section<br/><small>Please leave as None if all properties in this section have names</small></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="onb" class="control-label">Odd Numbers From</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="onb" name="onb" value="None" pattern="^\d*[13579]$|(None)" title="Odd Numbers only please with no spaces, or None">
            <span class="help-block">e.g. '1' or '111'</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="one" class="control-label">Odd Numbers To</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="one" name="one" value="None" pattern="^\d*[13579]$|(None)" title="Odd Numbers only please with no spaces, or None">
            <span class="help-block">e.g. '31' or '217'</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="enb" class="control-label">Even Numbers From</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="enb" name="enb" value="None" pattern="^\d*[02468]$|(None)" title="Even Numbers only please with no spaces, or None">
            <span class="help-block">e.g. '2' or '110'</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="ene" class="control-label">Even Numbers To</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="ene" name="ene" value="None" pattern="^\d*[02468]$|^(None)$" title="Even Numbers only please with no spaces, or None">
            <span class="help-block">e.g. '32' or '216'</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label for="rdclass" class="control-label">Road Class</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="rdclass" name="rdclass">
              <option>Unclassified</option>
              <option>A Road</option>
              <option>B Road</option>
              <option>C Road</option>
            </select>
            <span class="help-block">Leave as Unclassified if in any doubt.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label for="length" class="control-label">Length of this Street Section (whole no. metres)</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="length" name="length" value= 0 pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$" title="Whole number of metres please, no spaces!" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <!-- JS here to put in A B C / disable depending on what selected in rdclass box -->
            <label for="rdnum" class="control-label">Road Number</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="rdnum" name="rdnum" pattern="^[ABC][1-9][0-9]*$|^(None)$" title="Must be None, or A, B or C followed by a whole number for the road class, no spaces!" value="None" required>
            <span class="help-block">Only for A/B/C roads e.g. 'A232', 'C3241'</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label class="control-label left">Does one end of this street adjoin a TfL maintained street?</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="TfL">
              <option value="0">No</option>
              <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <!-- JS not working yet to disable only if no selected in rdclass box -->
            <label class="control-label"><br/>&nbsp;Road Number of Adjoining TfL Road?</label>

            <input class="form-control" pattern="^[ABC][1-9][0-9]*$|^(None)$"
                   title="Must be None, or A, B or C followed by a whole number, no spaces!" value="None" id="TfLroad" required>

           <span class="help-block">E.g. 'A232', 'B2441'</span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="centre">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Form</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Street</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in the HTML/script you provided.

1. The `<script>` content is executing before the form fields exist (`onload` code isn't implemented the way you've done it.)
2. You haven't picked a default value for `TfL`
3. You haven't disabled `TfLroad` by default
4. You've got a typo in a comparison.

Fixing in order:

1. move the `<script>` to the bottom of the page and remove the `onload` function.
2. assuming you want `No` selected by default:

   ```
     <select class="form-control" id="TfL">
       <option value="0" selected>No</option>
       <option value="1">Yes</option>
     </select>
   ```
3. Add `disabled` attribute

   ```
   <input class="form-control" pattern="^[ABC][1-9][0-9]*$|^(None)$" disabled
     title="Must be None, or A, B or C followed by a whole number, no spaces!" value="None" id="TfLroad" required>
   ```
4. usie `=` instead of `==` (or `===`):

   ```
   if(this.value = '0') {
   ```

Should be

```
    if(this.value === '0') {
```

(You could also rewrite the onchange handler):

```
document.getElementById('TfL').onchange = function () {
  document.getElementById("TfLroad").disabled = (this.value === '0');
}
```

Comment: That will always get you a disabled input.

Comment: Thanks @searlea Yes, finally, moving my script to bottom of page made it work! Thanks  == normally I get that right doh.. Used @Naren code in the end, purely because DOM part very new to me want understand. I am confused because I have other page: `function showExpl(){
        document.getElementById('Explanation').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('showbut').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('hidebut').style.display = "block";
}` _above_ table (not form), but still works perfectly. So non-form content loads before JS wherever JS is in the page?

Comment: The code in your comment just defines a function.  That's fine.  What's important is whether `showExpl()` gets called before or after the page finishes loading (if it gets called at all.)

Comment: Hi @searlea in that other page this function does get called and works. This JS code is above actual element in the page: `<h4 id="showbut" onclick="toggleExpl()">` but this 'showbut' id element in the text does not display when the page loads i.e. the second line of this JS code is clearly being executed, even though this JS is above the HTML content to which it refers.... sorry if you're too busy to answer just curious in case....

Comment: Hi @searlea again, just for the record, I changed to your two-liner as have other fields same page want same thing, does exactly what I think I asked for in the question. It is interesting someone decided to -1 you without apparently confirming your solution does in fact work, and you addressed each of my mistakes very concisely, you are the only person who pointed out my JS was wrong place in the page, enhanced my understanding, thanks! Only super pedantic issue is, if user selects Yes (value '1' for 'TfL' id), then reset button, the reset changes yes back to no, but leaves 'TfLroad' enabled.

Comment: Thanks - the -1 confused me too.  To fix reset behaviour add something like `id="TfLform"` to your `<form>` and then add a bit more JavaScript: `document.getElementById('TfLform').onreset = function () { document.getElementById("TfLroad").disabled = true; }`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of setting disabled through javascript you could add the disabled to the   HTML input element:

```
<input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" .... />
```

Then in your javascript:

```
document.getElementById('TfL').onchange = function () 
{
    if (this.value == '0') 
    {
        document.getElementById("TfLroad").disabled = true;
    }

    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("TfLroad").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will give you a disabled input. ALWAYS

Comment: Oh I thought he wanted it to be disabled and only working if the input changes. "I want 'TfLroad' to load as disabled by default, then if 'TfL' changes from No to Yes, then 'TfLroad' should be enabled."

Comment: He does (I missed that part of the question on first reading.)

Comment: Thanks @Mr. this may well be the simplest solution, as I noted to Mr. searlea lower down, crucially for me, I also needed to move JS to bottom of the page, so form content loads before the Javascript does (hope that is technically correct explanation!)

Answer (score 2):

`disabled` is a Boolean attribute. You don't disable an element by setting its attribute to `disabled=false`. The browser checks if your element HAS a `disabled` property and doesn't care if its `disabled=true`, `disabled=false`, `disabled=elephant`. In order to "enable" your element you must completely remove the `disabled` attribute.

This should work:

```
document.getElementById('TfL').onchange = function () {
    if(this.value == '0') {
        document.getElementById("TfLroad").disabled = "elephant";
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("TfLroad").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
```

Also when comparing two values use `==` and not `=`.

Comment: The code in the question shows he's updating the disabled _property_, not the attribute.  The code is fine wrt setting `element.disabled` to `true` or `false`.

Comment: The code is absolutely fine with `element.disabled` equals to `whatever` but it doesn't achieve what he asks for.

Comment: Thanks @VTodorov I am ruminating on what difference is between attribute and property, as fairly new to JS still.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is `load` event does not work on all elements, it only supports the below HTML tags.

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">,
<link>, <script> and <style>
```

Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp) to know more.

Also I have changed the logic for applying the initial disabled condition, please check it!

As an alternative you can watch for `document.ready` instead and then apply this change. Refer the below snippet.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('TfL'), input = document.getElementById("TfLroad");
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  if (select.value === '0') {
    input.disabled = true;
  } else {
    input.disabled = false;
  }
});

select.onchange = function() {
  if (this.value === '0') {
    input.disabled = true;
  } else {
    input.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Add A 'Dummy' Street</h2>

<p>You can create a Dummy street here, which you will be able to search for in this application. This is to demonstrate how a real Create &amp; Update Process could work for this application, without corrupting the original data. Dummy streets are indicated
  in search results.</p>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label for="stname" class="control-label">Street Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="stname" name="stname" pattern="^\S.{3,98}\S$" title="Sorry, you must type from 5 to 100 characters, and no space at beginning or end." placeholder="Full Street Name" required>
        <!--  required attribute needed because empty string bypasses the pattern regex. -->
        <span class="help-block">NB: No naughty word streets please, these will be deleted by admin!</span>
      </div>

      <!-- CR, CL, PR, 25, 16, 19, BE, KN, SC, TH, WA, WH -->
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="distr" class="control-label">Postal District</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="distr" name="distr">
              <option>Croydon (CR0, CR2, CR7 or CR9)</option>
              <option>Coulsdon CR5</option>
              <option>Purley CR8</option>
              <option>London SE25</option>
              <option>London SW16</option>
              <option>Kenley CR8</option>
              <option>South Croydon CR2</option>
              <option>Thornton Heath CR7</option>
              <option>Warlingham CR6</option>
              <option>Whyteleafe CR3</option>
              <option>Beckenham BR3</option>
            </select>
        <span class="help-block">NB: Original data uses postal district only, hence problem with several postcodes for Croydon.</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="maint" class="control-label">Who looks after this street?</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="maint" name="maint">
              <option>Croydon Borough</option>
              <option>Transport for London</option>
              <option>Private Road</option>
            </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="centre">Street Number Limits for this Street Section<br/><small>Please leave as None if all properties in this section have names</small></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="onb" class="control-label">Odd Numbers From</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="onb" name="onb" value="None" pattern="^\d*[13579]$|(None)" title="Odd Numbers only please with no spaces, or None">
        <span class="help-block">e.g. '1' or '111'</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="one" class="control-label">Odd Numbers To</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="one" name="one" value="None" pattern="^\d*[13579]$|(None)" title="Odd Numbers only please with no spaces, or None">
        <span class="help-block">e.g. '31' or '217'</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="enb" class="control-label">Even Numbers From</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="enb" name="enb" value="None" pattern="^\d*[02468]$|(None)" title="Even Numbers only please with no spaces, or None">
        <span class="help-block">e.g. '2' or '110'</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="ene" class="control-label">Even Numbers To</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ene" name="ene" value="None" pattern="^\d*[02468]$|^(None)$" title="Even Numbers only please with no spaces, or None">
        <span class="help-block">e.g. '32' or '216'</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label for="rdclass" class="control-label">Road Class</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="rdclass" name="rdclass">
              <option>Unclassified</option>
              <option>A Road</option>
              <option>B Road</option>
              <option>C Road</option>
            </select>
        <span class="help-block">Leave as Unclassified if in any doubt.</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label for="length" class="control-label">Length of this Street Section (whole no. metres)</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="length" name="length" value=0 pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$" title="Whole number of metres please, no spaces!" required>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <!-- JS here to put in A B C / disable depending on what selected in rdclass box -->
        <label for="rdnum" class="control-label">Road Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="rdnum" name="rdnum" pattern="^[ABC][1-9][0-9]*$|^(None)$" title="Must be None, or A, B or C followed by a whole number for the road class, no spaces!" value="None" required>
        <span class="help-block">Only for A/B/C roads e.g. 'A232', 'C3241'</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label class="control-label left">Does one end of this street adjoin a TfL maintained street?</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="TfL">
              <option value="0">No</option>
              <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <!-- JS not working yet to disable only if no selected in rdclass box -->
        <label class="control-label"><br/>&nbsp;Road Number of Adjoining TfL Road?</label>

        <input class="form-control" pattern="^[ABC][1-9][0-9]*$|^(None)$" title="Must be None, or A, B or C followed by a whole number, no spaces!" value="None" id="TfLroad" required>

        <span class="help-block">E.g. 'A232', 'B2441'</span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="centre">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Form</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Street</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Naren, I ran your code snippet and can see it works. I just chose yours as it looks clever and new thing I didn't know before. It doesn't work on my page, which means I guess i have something else outside the included code stopping it, in the base template perhaps. i did have problem before with the browser cache not showing changes, but downloaded Chrome Cache killer to stop this. I wonder if anything in the Bootstrap CSS might affect the JS here? My understanding is == should work here as well as ===

Comment: @WillCroxford when you refresh the page do `ctrl+shift+r` this will eliminate the catching problem, you're welcome!